# How add resource to M2M relationship in django-tastypie

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie

I try to build API for save some objects to user-favorite.
I have this class for user-profile:

```
class Profile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email =             models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    first_name =        models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    last_name =         models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)

    # some enother fields    

    USERNAME_FIELD =    'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS =   ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

And tastypie-API for profiles:

```
class ProfileResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset =  Profile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'profiles'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch']
        authentication = Authentication()#MultiAuthentication(ApiKeyAuthentication(), SessionAuthentication())
        authorization = Authorization()
```

And object with relation to profile

```
class News(models.Model):
    title =         models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Заголовок')
    add_to_favorite=models.ManyToManyField('profiles.Profile', related_query_name='favorite_news', blank=True)

class NewsResource(ModelResource):
    add_to_favorite = fields.OneToManyField(
        'profiles.api.ProfileResource',
        attribute='add_to_favorite',
        full=False, blank=True, null=True)    
    class Meta:
        queryset =  News.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'news'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch']
```

Now I try to execute this request

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "add_to_favorite":[
    {"id":3}
  ]
}
```

And got the error: `IntegrityError: column email is not unique`.

But the column email is unique. And all email's in database is unique.
How to fix my models and resources to resolve this problem?

Thanx!

Comment: Are you sure there's a Profile with an id of 3 though? If not tastypie might be trying to create a new one with that id, and a blank email.

Comment: Also, I think you want a ToManyField, not a OneToManyField, since it's representing a ManyToManyField. They're actually the same class, but are semantically different, so behavior could differ in the future.

Comment: Could you post a traceback for the IntegriyError?

Answer (score 0):

Your request

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "add_to_favorite":[
    {"id":3}
  ]
}
```

create a `News` with pk=1 and `UserProfile` with pk=3.

This request:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "add_to_favorite":['/api/v1/profile/3/']
}
```

create a `News` with pk=1 and attach `UserProfile` with pk=3 to `add_to_favorite` field.